# iphone popViewController

Tags: iphone

I am having a back button on my application hitting on which i have to go to the previous page. I think this will work using popViewController.

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Spend at least 15 minutes to read the *iOS Application Programming Guide*.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information on the problem and the code as well. Judging by your question if it is a Navigation Controlled app, yes popViewController method will work to pop the current view from the stack and go to the previous view on the navigation stack.

Comment: i am having xib called enterpage on which m having a more button clicking on which i get a scrollview of different images.Now i want to put back button on that scrollview so that after i click it shld take me back to enterpage.

Comment: Ok. So use a UINavigation Controller first. Your first view(with the button) and the second view (scroll view) are the two view objects on the UINavigation Controller object's stack. Try it.